# How to install Snowflake Connector in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to install snowflake connector for python version 2.7.10. Most of the instructions are for Python 3.6 and higher. I need to get the required libraries to make it work. So far this is what I have used but it is now working now.

```
sudo yum install libffi-devel
sudo pip install setuptools==40.8.0
sudo pip install snowflake-connector-python
sudo pip install snowflake-connector-python==1.7.9
sudo pip install ipaddress
sudo pip install cryptography==2.6.1 --no-cache-dir
sudo pip install azure_storage_common==1.4.0
sudo pip install azure_storage_blob==1.5.0
```

You might be asking why I am using Python 2.7. This is because I am using an old AWS EMR 4.7 and it's oozie workflow only works with Python 2.7.

Thanks,
David

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: According to this documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html the module you are trying to use does not support Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this, you should be able to run snowflake wit Python 2.7:

```
sudo yum install libffi-devel -y
sudo pip install setuptools==18.5
sudo pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/v2.3.9/tested_requirements/requirements_36.reqs
sudo pip install snowflake-connector-python==1.7.9
sudo pip install ipaddress==1.0.23

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography*

sudo pip install cryptography==2.6.1 --no-cache-dir
sudo pip install azure_storage_common==1.4.0
sudo pip install azure_storage_blob==1.5.0
```